# OpenGL application crashes when VBO is not used

Tags: opengl-es-2.0, vao

I am trying to draw objects without using VBO in OpenGL ES 2.0. My code tend to crash application from time to time (not always, even nothing is changed). The following is the code. I think the problem is that I only enable m_distLocation without sending any data to shader. All uniform values are properly set. I think the problem is only in attribute variables (m_posAttr and m_distLocation), binding.

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(m_posAttr);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(m_distLocation); 

int      posAttrSize           = sizeof(float) * 2;
GLintptr posAttrStart          = reinterpret_cast<GLintptr>(&vertices[0]);

glVertexAttribPointer(m_posAttr,      2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, posAttrSize, reinterpret_cast<GLvoid*>(posAttrStart));
glVertexAttribPointer(m_distLocation, 0, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

glBindAttribLocation(m_programID, m_posAttr, "posAttr" );
glBindAttribLocation(m_programID, m_distLocation, "distance" );

glUniform1i(m_patternLocation, -1);
glUniform4fv(m_colorAttr, 1, vColor);
glUniform1f(m_depthAttr, z);
glUniform1f(m_zoom, _zoom / 100);
glUniform2fv(m_scale, 1, _scale);
glUniform2fv(m_translate, 1, _trans);
glUniform1f(m_theta, _theta);


glDrawArrays(et, offsetInBytesFill, nVerticesFill );
glDisableVertexAttribArray(m_posAttr);
glDisableVertexAttribArray(m_distLocation);
```

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: What platform are you using? Android?

Comment: I am using Qt for my development.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of questionable aspects to the posted code fragment:

- `glBindAttribLocation()` only takes effect if it is called before `glLinkProgram()`. Otherwise, locations will be assigned automatically while linking, and you can't change them unless you re-link the program. To get the already assigned locations, you can replace those calls with:

  ```
  m_posAttr = glGetAttribLocation(m_programID, "posAttr");
  m_distLocation = glGetAttribLocation(m_programID, "distance");
  ```

  These statements obviously need to be placed before the values are used.
- The second argument to this call of `glVertexAttribPointer()` is illegal:

  ```
  glVertexAttribPointer(m_distLocation, 0, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
  ```

  The second argument is the number of components in the attribute, and needs to be 1, 2, 3, or 4. If the attribute is a scalar float, as the name suggests, the correct value would be 1.
- On the same call, since you are not using VBOs, the last argument has to be a valid pointer. Say if `distances` is an array/vector of distance values, the call should look like this:

  ```
  glVertexAttribPointer(m_distLocation, 1, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, &distances[0]);
  ```
- Based on what's suggested by the variable name, this also looks like it's possibly wrong:

  ```
  glDrawArrays(et, offsetInBytesFill, nVerticesFill);
  ```

  The second argument is the index of the first vertex to be drawn. It is not measured in bytes. For illustration, if you had attributes for 40 vertices in your vertex arrays, and you wanted to draw 10 vertices starting at vertex 20 (i.e. vertices 20 to 29), the call would be:

  ```
  glDrawArrays(et, 20, 10);
  ```

Comment: I think problem is ih passing m_distLocation. Thing is, I do not want to pass anything, just enable attribute variable.

Comment: Not sure I understand. If you enable the attribute variable, where do you expect the attribute values to come from, if you don't provide any attribute data?